# HttpSession setMaxInactiveInterval do not work exactly time has set

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, httpsession, spring-session

I have a spring web application. I using spring security for authentication and socket to push data to the client automatically.
Everything works well.
I have a Listener to set a timeout for a session like that

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionListener.class);

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
    LOGGER.info("{}: has created at : {}", sessionEvent.getSession().getId(), DateTimeUtil.toStringDate(new Date(), DateUtils.DATE_TIME_FORMAT));
    sessionEvent.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
    LOGGER.info("{}: has Destroyed at : {}", httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId(), DateTimeUtil.toStringDate(new Date(), DateUtils.DATE_TIME_FORMAT));
}
```

and the session timeout has set in the application:

```
server.session.cookie.max-age=2592000
server.session.timeout=2592000
```

as a result, my session will be inactive when the User has no performs an action in 60 seconds and my socket will disconnect.
it works, but it seems not exactly 60 seconds, as I saw, my socket will be a disconnect in more than ~2 minutes (~120 seconds).
so How does the "setMaxInactiveInterval" method work?

Comment: The thread that is cleaning up sessions runs once every minute (by default in tomcat). So a session timeout will never be less than a minute and more likely to be somewhere between 1 minute and 2 minutes, depending on when the thread has last been run and when the session timed out.

Comment: it means although my session is timeout but it only removes(something like that) after cleaning up runs?  @M.Deinum

Comment: The timeout is used to set the time on which to expire. The thread then checks all sessions to see if the time has passed, if so it will invalidate.